# C# error: System.Data.EvaluateException: Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32

Tags: c#, datarow

Using C#, I'm getting an exception:

> System.Data.EvaluateException: Cannot perform '=' operation on System.String and System.Int32.

I've traced it back to this code:

```
foreach (DataRow rows in dt.Rows){

...etc

string filter = string.Format("CUST_ID = " + rows[0]);
DataRow[] row = dt.Select(filter);
```

After the `foreach` I go to a bool which uses linq to find if a record with the same `CUST_ID` in DT exists in another datatable.  If false then I go to the string filter.  Here I take all of the records not existing in the second datatable and use SqlBulkCopy to put them all in a DB.

The funny thing is that just a hand full of records don't work.  There are about 7000 of them and roughly 50 will cause this exception.  I don't see any difference between the records.  So, I'm not sure what I'm missing.

EDIT:

One of the records has `CUST_ID` = 998947 which would throw the exception.

I change the `CUST_ID` to 987654 and there was no exception.

Comment: In which line does the code throw?

Comment: Which is the datatype of the field CUST_ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should enclose your input with apostrophes. Also, when using String.Format, provide format string and its parameters. Not just string, then is the String.Format call useless. Try this:

```
 string filter = String.Format("CUST_ID = '{0}'", rows[0].ToString());
```

EDIT: Sorry, misread your question. Don't care about apostrophes if your column is of integer type. The exception tells you that you are trying to compare string with int. If you are sure, they are of int, just little code review from me:

```
 string filter = String.Format("CUST_ID = {0}", rows[0].ToString());
```

You can also try to cast the CUST_ID to string and compare it with your value, but it isn't much nice solution.

Comment: The apostrophes were needed.  Removing them cause the same exception.  Thanks!